# Database.SqlQuery gives the The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql, asynchronous

I made a helper method for calling my queries in async and I added a retry counter of 5 just in case. It work most of the times but i still get all 5 tries with:

> The `SqlParameter` is already contained by another
>   SqlParameterCollection.

I call it from several places expecting one item or a list of items and with one or 2 params max.

my code

```
public static Object GetQueryResult(List<SqlParameter> parameters, Type dataType, string query, bool isList) {
    Object result = null;
    int retry = 0;
    while (result == null && retry < 5) {
        retry++;
        try {
            if (isList) {
                if (parameters.Count > 1)
                    result = lnssContext.Database.SqlQuery(dataType, query, parameters[0], parameters[1]).Cast<Object>().ToList();
                else
                    result = lnssContext.Database.SqlQuery(dataType, query, parameters[0]).Cast<Object>().ToList();
            } else {
                if (parameters.Count > 1)
                    result = lnssContext.Database.SqlQuery(dataType, query, parameters[0], parameters[1]).Cast<Object>().ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                else
                    result = lnssContext.Database.SqlQuery(dataType, query, parameters[0]).Cast<Object>().ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.Info("Query failed . Retry count:" + retry, e);
            result = null;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It is Linq-To-SQL isn't it?

Comment: lnssContext.Database   is a  System.Data.Entity.Database if that's what you mean. This is c# with mysql.

Comment: since i was iterating i simply cloned the parameters before calling it again and it worked