# EF Dynamic type - The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure will will give a dynamic result set

```
(Eg1. storedProcedureNameXX 4 - sql server result  may be 5 columns)
(Eg2. storedProcedureNameXX 1 - sql server result  may be 3 columns)
```

Lets assume i have added the dynamic columns in the Type Builder:

```
TypeBuilder builder = CreateTypeBuilder("MyDynamicAssembly", "MyModule", "MyType")<br>

//Todo:get the dynamic column names

CreateAutoImplementedProperty(builder, "column1", typeof(string));
CreateAutoImplementedProperty(builder, "column2", typeof(string));
CreateAutoImplementedProperty(builder, "column3", typeof(string));

Type resultType = builder.CreateType();
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("parm1", 1));

var  **p1** = entity.Database
    .SqlQuery(resultType, "exec storedProcedureNameXX @parm1", parameters.ToArray());
```

Error in P1 variable:

> "The SqlParameter is already contained by another
>   SqlParameterCollection" Unable to place ToList()

//Added methods used
private static TypeBuilder createTypeBuilder( string assemblyName, string moduleName, string typeName)
        {
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = AppDomain
                .CurrentDomain
                .DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName),
                                       AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
                .DefineDynamicModule(moduleName)
                .DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);
            typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
            return typeBuilder;
        }

        private static void createAutoImplementedProperty(
            TypeBuilder builder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            const string PrivateFieldPrefix = "m_";
            const string GetterPrefix = "get_";
            const string SetterPrefix = "set_";

```
        // Generate the field.
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = builder.DefineField(
            string.Concat(PrivateFieldPrefix, propertyName),
                          propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        // Generate the property
        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = builder.DefineProperty(
            propertyName, System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);

        // Property getter and setter attributes.
        MethodAttributes propertyMethodAttributes =
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
            MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

        // Define the getter method.
        MethodBuilder getterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(
            string.Concat(GetterPrefix, propertyName),
            propertyMethodAttributes, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        // Emit the IL code.
        // ldarg.0
        // ldfld,_field
        // ret
        ILGenerator getterILCode = getterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Define the setter method.
        MethodBuilder setterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(
            string.Concat(SetterPrefix, propertyName),
            propertyMethodAttributes, null, new Type[] { propertyType });

        // Emit the IL code.
        // ldarg.0
        // ldarg.1
        // stfld,_field
        // ret
        ILGenerator setterILCode = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getterMethod);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setterMethod);
    }
```

Comment: If you try to enumerate over `p1` twice, it will throw that error.

Comment: @davidg: it's a single execute..

Comment: Even just hovering over the `p1` variable with your mouse may cause it to materialise the data, meaning that your code later on will try to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this occurred as the effect of [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx). Usually simple `ToList()` call should work:

```
var p1 = entity.Database.SqlQuery(resultType, "exec storedProcedureNameXX @parm1", parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
```

If `ToList()` like above still doesn't work, try to clone existing `SqlParameter` instance and use it like this example:

```
var p1 = entity.Database.SqlQuery(resultType, "exec storedProcedureNameXX @parm1", 
                parameters.Select(x => ((ICloneable)x).Clone()).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Or with `Database.SqlQuery<T>`:

```
var p1 = entity.Database.SqlQuery<resultType>("exec storedProcedureNameXX @parm1", 
                    parameters.Select(x => ((ICloneable)x).Clone()).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Reference: [SqlParameter.ICloneable.Clone Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.system-icloneable-clone?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter_System_ICloneable_Clone)

Related issue: [Database.SqlQuery gives the The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186202/database-sqlquery-gives-the-the-sqlparameter-is-already-contained-by-another-sql)

Comment: I have already tried<br>var p1 = entity.Database.SqlQuery(resultType, "exec storedProcedureNameXX @parm1", parameters.ToArray()).ToList();<br>var p1 = entity.Database.SqlQuery(resultType, "exec storedProcedureNameXX @parm1", 
                parameters.Select(x => ((ICloneable)x).Clone()).ToArray()).ToList();<br> the tolist() is not appearing

Comment: I can't use as Database.SqlQuery<T>: since the resulttype is dynamic columns/ class.